# How to make IPC(Complex) in WebSphere Portal using two different war files?

Tags: websphere-portal

Hi i tried to develop an application using IPC in WebSpherePortal using two different war files.Am trying to transfer one bean object,for that i have placed one jar file in ../WebSpherePortal/PortalServer/shared/app. Even am getting class cast exception.Can any one answer this question.

Comment: I have generated the jar file of the bean which is using in both Portlets.I have placed in the both lib folder.Later i have placed the jar file in C:\IBM\WebSpherPortal\PortalServer\shared\app\CommonBean.jar.And i have defined this as a shared library under environment->shared libraries.After then I have added the shared library under Servers -> Application Servers -> Websphere_Portal -> Java and Process Management -> ClassLoader.

Answer (score 0):

What you attempted will not work. The classloader with WAS works generally so that every application is separated from each others. You can not share any classes because the classloaders will **not** be able to understand that the two classes - even when loaded from the same jar - are actually the same. What you need to do is to serialize ("implements Serializable", plus ensure that you really do serialize every Object) every Object before you share them.

Some approaches you could generally take are [ICE](http://www.zeroc.com/icej.html) or [Spring Remoting](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html).